# Data inconsistency between Galera cluster nodes

Tags: mariadb, galera

We currently have a mariab galera cluster with 7 nodes; 3 on local and 4 on Azure cloud. All nodes are using Mariadb 10.5.16 version. My issue is that on my local cluster when I run the following query:

```
SELECT created_at,updated_at FROM stuffs WHERE ref_num = "XXX123";
```

My Local Nodes return: (incorrect time)

| created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12-18 02:00:19 | 2020-12-18 02:01:51 |

While my Azure nodes return: (correct time)

| created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12-17 13:00:19 | 2020-12-17 13:01:51 |

I checked the date and time on the servers and they return the same. Same with select NOW() and TIMESTAMP().

When the application inserts and fetched the data, it inserts and returns the correct date and time. But when queried from the local nodes it returns a different value.

Will there be any issues with the data itself on the database? Is there any way to fix this mismatch? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is that column a `TIMESTAMP`?  Azure systems are probably set to UTC as their timezone; what timezone are the local nodes?

TIMESTAMP is converted to local time when `SELECTing`.  So, those dates are probably the "same".

`DATETIME`, on the other hand, can be thought of as a picture of a clock -- no TZ adjustment.

Comment: We have our local on PST, but after checking it seems that our Azure servers use EDT as their timezone. I checked the data type and yes both use TIMESTAMP data.